# Jplayer Circle Player not playing mp3 file in Chrome

Tags: jplayer

I've updated a theme so that all pages are loaded via ajax. On one of the pages I play mp3's using jplayer Circle player which works fine in firefox and safari but not in Chrome.

Here is the init script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer(".jquery_jplayer_'.$counter.'",
{
    mp3: "'.$track->album_track_mp3_url.'",

}, {
    cssSelectorAncestor: ".cp_container_'.$counter.'",
    swfPath: "'.get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/frontend/Jplayer.swf",
    wmode: "window",
    supplied: "mp3"
});

});
```

Any ideas why its not working in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer(".jquery_jplayer_'.$counter.'",
{
    mp3: "'.$track->album_track_mp3_url.'",

}, 
{
    cssSelectorAncestor: ".cp_container_'.$counter.'",
    swfPath: "'.get_template_directory_uri().'/scripts/frontend/Jplayer.swf",
    wmode: "window",
    supplied: "mp3",
    solution: "flash, html"// after adding a line of code it will work on chrome
});

});
```